# using static variable in different controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, static-variables

i'm making an application where i'm saving user information in user controller of my code igniter application inside a static variable, now i want to access static variable in other controller, how can i approach that? my code here

```
<?php 
     class User extends CI_Controller{
          public static $user_data = array();
          public __construct()
          {
               parent::__construct();
               self::$user_data = array('value'); // values from the model
          }
     }
     // now i can user that static variable from the view in this controller
     class Friends extends CI_Controller{
          public __construct()
          {
               parent::__construct();
               if(User::$user_data->isFriends)
               {
                     redirect('person/'.User::$user_data->id);
               }
          }
     }
     // how can i access this functionality in codeigniter? it gives error undefined class User not found
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static::$user_data = array('value')
```

shouldn't it be self::... in your User class?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code.

As you have defined that `$user_data` is an array with `public static $user_data = array();` at the top of the `User` class, it is unnecessary to redefine it on line 7, i.e. `self::$user_data = array('value');`

Second issue is that the `$user_data` array will only contain one element, 'value'. I assume by lines 15 and 17 (`User::$user_data->isFriends` and `User::$user_data->id`), you are looking for two elements, 'isFriends' and 'id', these will not exist.

This brings me to another issue, the syntax you are using to get an element of the `$user_data` array will not work. The syntax '`->`' followed by a property name is used for variables of type `Object`, and cannot be used for an associative array.

Instead, you should use - for example - `$user_data['isFriends']`.

I have updated your code below...

```
<?php 
 class User extends CI_Controller{
      public static $user_data = array();
      public __construct()
      {
           parent::__construct();
           // this does the same thing as self::$user_data = array('value');
           // but without unnecessarily declaring the array again.
           self::$user_data[] = 'value';
      }
 }
 // now i can user that static variable from the view in this controller
 class Friends extends CI_Controller{
      public __construct()
      {
           parent::__construct();
           if(User::$user_data['isFriends'])
           {
                 redirect('person/'.User::$user_data['id']);
           }
      }
 }
 // how can i access this functionality in codeigniter? it gives error undefined class User not found
```

Try running the code and let me know what errors are being displayed and I will try and resolve them by updating my answer